# how to get the data count from sqlite data base in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays, sqlite

I have sqlite database and the data base format is

table name = Master project

```
column 0(M_ID) column 1(M_ISSUE)
M1               i1
M1               i2
M1               i3
M2               x
M2               y 
M2               z
M3               1 
M3               2
```

In the above table i need to display M_ID issues count, (ex:- M_ID(M1) is having 3 issues(i1,i2,i3) like wise M2 and M3.

here is the my source code

```
for (int i = 0; i < [masterProjIDArray count]; i++)
{
    MySQLite *sqlobj = [[MySQLite alloc] initWithSQLFile:@"myDb"];
    [sqlobj openDb];
    NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT *FROM MASTER_PRJ_DETAILS WHERE M_ID = \'%@\'", [masterProjIDArray objectAtIndex:i]];
    NSLog(@"SQL query:%@", query);
    [sqlobj readDb:query];

    while ([sqlobj hasNextRow])
    {
        NSString *mProjIssuesID = [sqlobj getColumn:1 type:@"text"];

        [masterProjIssueIDArray addObject:mProjIssuesID];
    }
    NSLog(@"issueCount:%@", masterProjIssueIDArray);

    [sqlobj closeDb];
}
[sqlobj release];
```

Please give me some suggestion for displaying the M_ID issues individual count.

Answer (score 0):

NSLog(@"issueCount:%d", [masterProjIssueIDArray count]);

Answer (score 0):

there are two ways you can go for count

Count with array

```
[masterProjIssueIDArray count]
```

or count in database

```
SELECT count(*) FROM MASTER_PRJ_DETAILS
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: yes i know the overall count but i dont know how to display individual count
ex:- M1 count
     M2 count 
     M3 count

Comment: develop sqlquery in such way then

Answer (score 0):

```
        MySQLite *sqlobj = [[MySQLite alloc] initWithSQLFile:@"myDb"];
        [sqlobj openDb];
        NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT *FROM MASTER_PRJ_DETAILS WHERE M_ID = '%@'",M1];

      NSLog(@"SQL query:%@", query);
     NSMutableArray *arrydata= [sqlobj readDb:query];             
       //You got 3 records...


         for (int i = 0; i < [arrydata count]; i++)
         {
               NSMUtableDisctionry *dist=[arrydata objectAtIndex:i];
               NSString *strIsuue=[dist objectforkey:@"M_ISSUE"];
               [masterProjIssueIDArray addObject:strIsuue];

               NSLog(@"issueCount:%@", masterProjIssueIDArray);


  } 
  [sqlobj closeDb];
  [sqlobj release];
```

i hope its working....